# Codeigniter: how to access css files from different views?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

My problem is that i cant seem to load my .css and .js files on my other views. The only single view that can access .css and .js files is my default_controller's index() function. The destination folder doesn't have any problem though because it can be accessed by the index function.

I want my .css and .js files be accessible to all my views.

Comment: did you put your css and js on the head tag? did you put your css url like this ? (http://localhost/codeigniterfolder/img/stylemainpage.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add the following link to your header file**

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/hello.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/hello.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

**For css**

```
 make the folder in codeigniter folder like following
       codeigniter->css->hello.css
```

**For js**

```
 make the folder in codeigniter folder like following
       codeigniter->js->hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load all your JS and CSS files with absolute URL:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>path_to/index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>path_to/index.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

Now, this ensures that all your files are available to all your views.